# Rewrite rule with htaccess, redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to execute this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^featured$ home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

But what I get is:

```
http://apps.com/var/www/vhosts/apps.com/httpdocs/iphone/home.php?featurez=1
```

I tried to overcome it with PT tags...but nothing has an effect on it :(..whats the problem and how do I solve it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you leave off the leading slash in your rule's target, when apache needs to guess whether the path is a URI path or a file path, it guesses wrong. You can help apache out by either adding a leading slash (or making the target an absolute URI) or adding a rewrite base:

```
RewriteBase /iphone/
RewriteRule ^featured$ home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

(or whatever the base URI is for your request)

Or change the target to an absolute URI:

```
RewriteRule ^featured$ /iphone/home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

This is assuming your htaccess file is sitting in the directory "iphone" inside your document root, and to access the redirect you go to `http://your.domain/iphone/featured`. Otherwise, just get rid of all the `iphone/` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^featured$ home.php?featurez=1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a solution along those lines: Alias /iphone /var/www/vhosts/apps.com/httpdocs

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^featured$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

Comment: didnt work.. i think the error comes from somwhere above..but i dont know where

Comment: Clear your browser's cache and try again!