# ModRewrite in htaccess sends me to the full path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got those two rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories$ home.php?categories=1[L,NC,PT,R=301]
RewriteRule ^featured$ home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

The problem is that teh categories work and the featured doesnt work.
works:

```
 http://apps.com/iphone/categories
```

doesnt work:

```
 http://apps.com/iphone/featured
```

The second rule that doesnt work sends me to here

```
 http://apps.com/var/www/vhosts/apps.com/httpdocs/iphone/home.php?featurez=1
```

It seems to send me the root of the root of my directory and that whole thing is prefixed with the root of my site..why?

How is that possible.

Comment: Why don't you people start looking at the log? mod_rewrite brings two commands: `RewriteLog` and `RewritelogLevel`, Set the log level to maybe 7 and have a look what it explains about what is going on inside the rewrite engine when you make a request. The manual is excellent, I suggest you _read_ the manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I am aware of the way to debug.. but it doesnt help.. i can see what it is doing above.. it stops in the middle of the redirect.. and i havent got access to the apache on my server

Comment: You haven't got access to a server on your own system? But you say you can evaluate the logs? Strange... And what on earth does 'stops in the middle' mean? Please post the excerpt of the rewrite log file.

Comment: look above.. how do u explain that , i have two rules,, they are similar in their pattern.. one works, and the other one gives me the whole directory pattern prefixed with the site root. What the log should show me is how it evaluates 'featured'. it doesnt help much.. it shouldnt even go to the very root of the servers directory.. why does it do that?

Comment: BTW.. the link that you sent me arkascha..explains nothing about debuggin

Comment: Logging and Debugging are two separate things. The link refers to the excellent documentation of the software you are using: the rewrite module. Inside you find the usage explanation of two commands I mentioned. I thought you said you know those commands?

Comment: When you raise the `RewriteLogLevel` enough you get loads of valuable information about each step the rewrite engine goes through. This is the information required. It will tell you exactly where the additional tokens inside the url come from you do not expect to show up there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rewrite conditions *only apply to the immediately following rule*, so your condition doesn't apply to the "featured" rule at all. You'll have to duplicate it.
2. Apache tries to guess whether the target of a rule is a URL-path or a file-path, and it's guessing incorrectly. You can try to fix it by either including a rewrite base or make your targets absolute URL-paths.

I've already answered this in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13292201/851273) using either of those solutions will fix the file-path appearing in the redirect.

```
RewriteBase /iphone/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories$ home.php?categories=1[L,NC,PT,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [NC]
RewriteRule ^featured$ home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [NC]
RewriteRule ^categories$ /iphone/home.php?categories=1[L,NC,PT,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone [NC]
RewriteRule ^featured$ /iphone/home.php?featurez=1 [L,NC,PT,R=301]
```

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd is the htaccess file in the /iphone/ directory? or your document root?

Comment: inside the iphone directory.. i tried to apply many of the solutions.. i also read on how to debug the rules... and log the mod rewrite.. This what puzzles me:  apps.com/var/www/vhosts/apps.com/httpdocs/iphone/home.php?featurez=1
one part of it is my site root, the other part of it is my full directory..why does it happen..why there such a mix.. the apache seems to not complete the rewrite process

Comment: What causes the stupid redirect is this flag: R=301.. it screws everything